# Jaxb order of the xmlns:xsi and xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation

Tags: jaxb, xml-namespaces

I am using JAXB to create an xml.
Used 
            marshaller.setProperty(
                    Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION,
                    "bla-bla.xsd");

the xml being generated is

```
<Interface xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bla-bla.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

however the application that is parsing this xml for some reason is not parse it as they need it in this format

```
<Interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bla-bla.xsd">
```

changing the target application is not an option :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach leveraging JAXB and StAX appears to give you the desired output, but since the order of attributes is not significant it is not guaranteed to always work.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Interface.class);

        XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "bla-bla.xsd");
        marshaller.marshal(new Interface(), xsw);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><Interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bla-bla.xsd"></Interface>
```

Comment: thanks! but as you mentioned the issue still remains, that we cannot control the order. I had done the same thing just used a file writer as i needed to write to a file.